# Load a JSON object from a file

Tags: json, haxe

I try to parse a JSON object (in Haxe) included in a file, but it's not working. 
When I try to parse a JSON object from a var in the class, it's working very well but that's not the case when the JSON is in a file, so I try to open the file and get the object inside.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 10):

Parsing json is as simple as `haxe.Json.parse(jsonvar)`. The problem you are experiencing is probably that you are using a target that doesn't support accessing files on the system (like JS for the browser or Flash for example).
The solutions are multiple. If you are loading a configuration piece of data you can use a macro and do something like this:

```
class Config {
  // path is relative to where haxe is executed
  macro public static function json(path : String) {
    var value = sys.io.File.getContent(path),
        json = haxe.Json.parse(value);
    return macro $v{json};
  }
}
```

And you use in your code with:

```
var conf = Config.json("myfile.json");
```

Note that in this scenario conf is initialized at compile time and there is no loading at runtime. That implies that if you make any changes to `myfile.json` you will not see them until you recompile.

The other scenario is that you load your file at runtime. In that case the solution is often specific to your target (for JS in the browser you might want to make an AJAX call, for Neko or OpenFL you can load a file directly from the system similarly to what explained before).

Comment: Dude you saved me hours of banging my head on the wall, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

TJSON can take care of the JSON parsing: https://github.com/martamius/TJSON

```
var myObject = TJSON.parse(sys.io.File.getContent('filename.json'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you post code in future - to at least add more context.

Have you used [JSON parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the strings you read in from the file?

Comment: Explicit explanation of "not working" would also be nice. Do you get an error, if so what?

Comment: The question appears to be about a language called Haxe, not JS.

Comment: I guessed, but there wasn't any code in the context.